On covariant form of Lorentz equation
The non-relativistic version of Lorentz equation has the form
$$m\frac{d\vec{v}}{dt}=q(\vec{E}+\vec{v}\times\vec{B}) $$
Where $\vec{v}, \vec{E}, \vec{B}$ refers to the velocity of charged particle, electric field and magnetic field measured with respect to a given observer respectively. The usual extension of this equation in flat spacetime has the form
$$\frac{dp^a}{d\tau}=q{F^a}_bv^b$$
where $p^a$, $v^a$ has the interpretation of 4-momentum, 4-velocity of the charged particle. What I'm unsure of is whether these two expressions of the Lorentz equation are really equivalent. There are two issues with the relativistic form:

$F_{ab}$ can be written as $2E_{[a}u_{b]}+e_{abc}B^c$ where E, B are electric and magnetic fields measured wrt a time like observer travelling with velocity $u$ (unit time-like). On plugging this expression in the relativistic Lorentz equation we see that it has the form of ($E+v\times B$) only for the special case where $u=(1, 0,0,0) $

Unlike in non-relativistic case, here we interpret $v^a$ as the 4-velocity of the charged particle and not the relative velocity measured wrt the observer $u$


It seems to me that if $\beta^a$ refers to relative velocity between $v^a$ and $u^a$ then the following expression can also be the candidate for relativistic Lorentz equation:
$$m\frac{d\beta^a}{d\tau}=q(E^a+{e^a}_{bc}\beta^bB^c) $$ I don't know if there is any flaw in my interpretation of standard Lorentz equation

"$F_{ab}$ can be written as $2E_{[a}u_{b]}+e_{abc}B^c$"
I do not see how this can work. Do you have a reference, preferably a good textbook?
Your notation $v$ is ambiguous. In your 2nd and 3d equation $a,b,c$ mean different things.

What is the distinction between "the four-velocity of the charged particle" and "the relative velocity measured w.r.t. the observer"?  An object's four-velocity in a given reference frame is its (four-)velocity relative to that frame.

@my2cts The decomposition of F_ab into its electric and magnetic parts are given, for eg, in "Relativistic Cosmology" by G. F. R. Ellis, Roy Maartens and A. H. McCallum. The  indices a, b, c are spacetime indices everywhere. The $E^a$ field for eg has zero time component. Same for the magnetic field. This essentially follows from projection of F_ab
parallel and orthogonal to $u^a$ . The spatial components are orthogonal to $u^a$.The same applies for 3d levi-civita which is $e_{abc}=e_{abcd}u^d$ (the time component is naturally zero due to antisymmetry of levi-civita)

@MichaelSeifert  I think this is more of a semantics thing : when it comes to "relative velocity" in the context of SR or GR, I have seen the following definition : $v^a=\Gamma (u^a+\beta^a) $ such that $u^a\beta_a=0$ , which gives $\Gamma = 1/\sqrt{1-\beta^2}$ . The $\beta^a$ is the relative velocity (see arxiv:gr-qc/0506032v5). If I take your definition and the decomposition of F_ab which I mentioned above, it would seem that the standard Lorentz force is defined wrt some co-moving observer $u^a$. But is this really the case?

If this is true then I think the final expression expression I wrote at the bottom is for arbitrary reference frame where the observer is no longer static anymore

'The decomposition of F_ab into its electric and magnetic parts' are in any textbook that treats the covariant formulation of electromagnetism. E and B are not vectors of their own but components of the antisymmetric field tensor F conform their transformation law under a velocity boost.

Yes I understand that. I think, the source of my confusion is whether we want our Lorentz force to look like q(E+v×B) wrt an arbitrary observer... Or just for the special case of a stationary observer. The third equation I wrote resemble (E+v×B) for any observer but it isn't equivalent to the standard Lorentz force

That would be $m {d \gamma \beta \over dt}$ and it will have the same form in any reference frame. In a different frame E,B,v,$\gamma$ will be different but the equation will look the same.

The first two expression are clearly not equivalent. The first is the low velocity limit of the second.
The second equation is correct if $p^a$ denotes $mu^a = m \gamma dx^a/dt$ and $u^a  = dx^a/dt$, setting $c=1$. $a,b,c$ should run over $t,x,y,z$.
The third equation is incorrect. Also it is not Lorentz covariant as $a,b,c$ run over $x,y,z$, since $\beta^t$, $E^t$ and $B^t$ have no meaning.
Not the answer you wanted to hear perhaps :-).
